# Обновление бд через Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Не знаю почему не происходит обновление столбца status в бд:
Возможно $request->get('id')]=null?
Как тогда получить id?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$request->input('my_ch')` ?

Answer (score 0):

`Request->get(), Request->input()` достают данные из формы.

Вы же передаете id в url, значит надо контроллер обозначивать так:

```
public function checkBoxChange(int $id, Request $request){
   // тут запрос к бд с $id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оптимально сделать в форме невидимое поле с этим id. Тогда его можно будет нормально получить из реквеста.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$task->id}}" />
```